# Failing to fetch data from json using fetch in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, react-native, fetch

So I am using a fake backend called json server and I am trying to fetch data from it but it is throwing this error

**[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: Network request failed]**

This is what my code looks like starting with the json server file

```
{
    "listings": [
      { 
        "id": 0,
        "image": "../app/assets/jacket.jpg",
        "title": "Red jacket for sale",
        "subtitle": "$400"
      },
      { 
        "id": 1,
        "image": "../app/assets/couch.jpg",
        "title": "Nice couch for basking in",
        "subtitle": "$100"
      },
      { 
        "id": 2,
        "image": "../app/assets/image.jpg",
        "title": "Just an image for sale nje",
        "subtitle": "$10"
      }
    ]
  }
```

And then my logic file where i call using fetch

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'

export default function ItemsScreen() {
    const [listings, setlistings] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch("http://localhost:8000/listings")
            .then(res => {
                return res.json();
            })
            .then(data => {
                setlistings(data)
            })
    }, []);

    return (
        <View>
            {listings && listings.map(listing => (
                <View key={listing.id}>
                    <Text>{listing.title}</Text>
                    <Text>{listing.subtitle}</Text>
                </View>
            ))}
        </View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({})
```

And finally my App.js file

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import { Button, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'

import ItemsScreen from './app/screens/ItemsScreen'

export default function App() {

  return (
        <ItemsScreen />
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({})
```

This is all of it. Where could I be going wrong?

Comment: There is no `.catch` block on the `fetch` Promise chain. As for why you've a network request failed, what debugging have you done? Is the server running? Have you correctly formatted the GET request? How is the server handling the requests? Is the response properly formatted? Is your code properly processing the response? Etc...

Comment: What if you simply go to `http://localhost:8000/listings` in your browser? So you'll know if your server is actually running

Comment: Probably some CORS related issue on the server side. This happens when your app and server are on another domain or port.  Try to debug using the available developer tools for the framework or browser

Comment: @JeremyThille yes the server is running and the data is showing on the browser but it will not be rendered on the expo app

Comment: What about adding `.catch( error => console.log(error) )`? What does it say?

Comment: @JeremyThille i just did and now it is saying "network error failed"

Comment: More details in the network tab? What's the error code, the complete server resonse? Also, there should be plenty of logs in the terminal that runs `json-server --watch db.json`. If there is a problem, it should appear there

Comment: @JeremyThille It is very strange because there's no errors when I run the server It must be something to do with the fetch. This is the error "[TypeError: Network request failed]"